# High ping on Turk Telekom

Tags: networking, ping, europe

I see high ping(60-80ms) in Europe(Germany, Ireland, UK) servers. What can I do for reduce ping? Turk Telekom ADSL connection.

I tried antivirus scan and use Complete Internet Repair.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFkQ6.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Ping speed of 60-80ms is not that bad, and there is not much that you can do
from your computer in software to improve it.

Getting a faster cable connection and/or better modem from Turk Telekom,
or comparing with another ISP if possible, is just about the most that you can do.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where you live, your programs running at the background and the placement of the servers of the game.

With a ping of 1ms, he is probably hosting the game, if he is not then it is pretty impossible because even on lan you get 5ms. 
And there is no need complain about having 45 ping, i have 80 ping at most when i play, playing online games on 45 ping is fine and there is no visible lag at all, you will start seeing lag when you play in servers where you have 120 ping.
If you still think that 45 ping is making playing online "really hard" then try figuring out how the game's servers work, is someone hosting it like in call of duty or are there servers that host the games like in counter strike.
to lower your ping open the task manager and check what program uses your internet, if you want, and it will not harm your computer close it and it will lower your ping, not by a lot but by a little (it may not help at all, depends on how much bandwidth it uses).

http://www.giantbomb.com/pc/3045-94/forums/which-are-acceptable-ping-values-topic-is-from-201-402543/

"Ping below 100 is good, below 50 is excellent. I think the maximum acceptable value for ping is 150ms. "

Source: [Higher ping than usual ping in my country](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3019890/higher-ping-usual-ping-country.html)